# How to disable the overflow protectors

Tags: gdb, buffer-overflow

When I try to experiment on **buffer overflows**, I set `randomize_va_space` to `0` and I set the `-fno-stack-protector` flag but my experiments still don't work with newer kernels ?.

Answer (score 1):

Don't work how? This question is extremely lacking in detail.

First, you can disable aslr for given process with setarch -R. Two, I suspect you have shellcode which executes itself from the stack, which is mapped non-exec. This can be remedied with -zexecstack.

I strongly suggest you get a distro prepared for beginners.  https://exploit.education/ has some excellent Overflow examples that can be setup in a Virtual Environment.

Comment: I agree.  You should share all of your compiler flags otherwise it is hard to answer.